"All pair coeffs are not set" Error in LAMMPS using smd/tlsph Pair Style
Hello LAMMPS Community,
I'm working on a simulation project using LAMMPS and have encountered a persistent error that I'm struggling to resolve. My simulation involves a 3D model with two types of atoms defined using the smd/tlsph pair style. Despite having set up my pair coefficients as required for this pair style, I keep receiving the error: "All pair coeffs are not set" when I attempt to run the simulation. Below is the relevant section of my input script:
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------##
clear  # Clear all previous LAMMPS settings
##---------------------------Variable Setup-----------------------------------##
variable timestep equal 0.00001  # Define the timestep for the simulation
####################################################################################################
variable E equal 1.0 # Young’s modulus
variable nu equal 0.3 # Poisson ratio
variable rho equal 1 # initial mass density
variable q1 equal 0.06 # standard artificial viscosity linear coefficient
variable q2 equal 0.0 # standard artificial viscosity quadratic coefficient
variable hg equal 10.0 # hourglass control coefficient
variable cp equal 1.0 # heat capacity of material -- not used here
##-----------------------Simulation Space Setup-------------------------------##
units micro
dimension 3
boundary p p p
atom_style smd
newton off
atom_modify map array
##---------------------Simulation Box and Atom Definition---------------------##
region mybox block 0 1000 0 700 -10 20
create_box 2 mybox
lattice sc 2
create_atoms 1 mesh I8_6_Final.stl units box
create_atoms 2 mesh I8_2_Final.stl units box
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------##
group other type 1
group eip type 2
group tlsph type 1 2
##-------------------Pair and Bond Style Setup--------------------------------##
pair_style smd/tlsph
pair_coeff 1 1 *COMMON ${rho} ${E} ${nu} ${q1} ${q2} ${hg} ${cp} &
*END
pair_coeff 2 2 *COMMON ${rho} ${E} ${nu} ${q1} ${q2} ${hg} ${cp} &
*END
##----------------------------------##
......
ERROR: All pair coeffs are not set (src/MACHDYN/pair_smd_tlsph.cpp:1558)
From what I understand, the smd/tlsph style should only require pair coefficients for interactions within the same atom type, which I have provided. I'm not sure why the simulation is not recognizing the set pair coefficients for each type.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

I fixed this by including the smd/hertz pair_style with the smd/tlsph pair_style
